# How to verify any email with php

Tags: php, email

I am working with a form. Where user enters their email, I can validate the email through regex. But what I need is like [this](https://email-checker.net/check). After searching, I found a solution [here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-email-validator). The as it checks the MX record of the email. But still it does not work for me fine, because when I gave a rough email like : `ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh@yahoo.com` my form accepted it, and when I gave the same email on the other website, it rejected the email. It might be the problem with my logic I don't know, below is my code where I am verifying the email.

```js
if(isset($_GET["saveData"])){

 $_appid = $_GET["appid"];
 $_name = $_GET["name"];
 $_email = $_GET["email"];
 $_pass = $_GET["pass"];
 $_applink = $_GET["applink"];

 function domain_exists($email, $record = 'MX'){
  list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
  return checkdnsrr($domain, $record);
 }


 if(!empty($_appid) && !empty($_name) && !empty($_email) && !empty($_pass) && !empty($_applink)){


  if(!domain_exists($_email) OR !filter_var($_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   echo "email_prb";
  }  else{

   $sl = "SELECT * FROM fb_data WHERE useremail = '$_email' OR fbappid = '$_appid' ";
   $count = $con->query($sl);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($count)>0){ 
    echo "exists";
   }else{
    $in = "INSERT INTO fb_data VALUES(NULL,'$_name','$_email','$_pass','$_applink','$_appid',1,0)";
    if ($con->query($in)) {
     echo "Inserted";
    }
   }
  }
 } else{

    echo "empty";
 }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong (or "rought") with `ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh@yahoo.com` though?

Comment: The email verification through MX mean, it checks the email of any domain, that if this email exists or not

Comment: MX check means it only checks the authoritative dns has an MX record for the domain.

Comment: Additionally, read something about sql injections: at the moment anybody can insert anything into your `fb_data` table.

Comment: It seems to me, that `checkdnsrr()` only checks whether a given domain name has an `MX` record. It does not validate the actual username part.

Comment: The only cross platform way to verify an email address actually exists, is to send an email to the address and require the user to confirm receipt of said email. E.g. by clicking a link or entering a verification code.

Comment: @cars10m how would I validate the username part as well

Comment: @fubar yes you are right, but this is not that much important at this point, I am building it just for a text purpose

Comment: It looks like https://email-checker.net/check does more then just check the DNS record. They also send a "simulated" mail to the recipient and check for a response. You can buy their services through an API if you want, otherwise it is up to you to build a similar system yourself ...

Comment: Ohk Gotcha. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Kindly Use mysqli or Pdo.. your code is vulnerable to sql injection, try to add mysql escape. but i have rewritten your PHP below without changing query.

Filter validate email will check for the correct email format, so you dont need checking for @. but if you filter the @example.com you need a custom filter for that.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["saveData"])){

    $_appid = $_GET["appid"];
    $_name = $_GET["name"];
    $_email = $_GET["email"];
    $_pass = $_GET["pass"];
    $_applink = $_GET["applink"];

    function domain_exists($email, $record = 'MX'){
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
        return checkdnsrr($domain, $record);
    }


    if(!empty($_appid) && !empty($_name) && !empty($_email) && !empty($_pass) && !empty($_applink)){


        if((!domain_exists($_email)) && (!filter_var($_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
            echo "email_prb";
        }  else{

            $sl = "SELECT * FROM `fb_data` WHERE `useremail` = '$_email' OR `fbappid` = '$_appid' ";
            $count = $con->query($sl);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($count)>0){ 
                echo "exists";
            }else{
                $in = "INSERT INTO `fb_data` VALUES(NULL,'$_name','$_email','$_pass','$_applink','$_appid',1,0)";
                if ($con->query($in)) {
                    echo "Inserted";
                }
            }
        }
    } else{

       echo "empty";
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

on this part of your code

```
if(!domain_exists($_email) OR !filter_var($_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

change the "OR" to ||. Like this

```
if(!domain_exists($_email) || !filter_var($_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Comment: what would it change?